# Running .exe file by CreateProcess cannot generate .txt file

Tags: c++, exe, createprocess

I have a `hello.cpp` file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    ofstream file;
    file.open("codebind.txt");
    file << "this text is written using C++\n" << "This is a number: " << 10;
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling this file by `g++` using command prompt: `g++ -o output hello.cpp`, it generated a `output.exe` file. Then, I managed to run this `output.exe` file in another `.cpp` program called `program.cpp`using `CreateProcess()` ([link for code](http://codepad.org/0mx7SNgM)). Unfortunately, when I hit Build, the system did not create any `codebind.txt` file despite the fact that the `exitcode` variable in `program.cpp` had a value of 0 as expected. Then I tried going to Explorer and running `hello.exe` mannually, it created the `codebind.txt` file. 
**Could someone tell me what's wrong with my `program.cpp` file and how to create `codebind.txt` using `CreateProcess`? Any help will be appreciated!**

Comment: Does `CreateProcess` executes `output.exe`?

Comment: As the file is created without an absolute path, it is created in the current directory. You should control what is that directory.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thank you, I finally found my problem, the `codebind.txt` is located in the project that contains `program.cpp`